# Can't import NumPy on Mountain Lion

Tags: python, numpy, nltk, osx-mountain-lion

Really struggling to get nltk to work. Used the Scipy Superpack to download what I thought was solution, but get the following error:

```
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    from collocations import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 38, in <module>
    from nltk.metrics import ContingencyMeasures, BigramAssocMeasures, TrigramAssocMeasures
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/metrics/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from nltk.metrics.segmentation    import windowdiff, ghd, pk
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/metrics/segmentation.py", line 44, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_5c944b9_20120828-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_5c944b9_20120828-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_5c944b9_20120828-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_5c944b9_20120828-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_5c944b9_20120828-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import multiarray
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_5c944b9_20120828-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_5c944b9_20120828-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/multiarray.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_5c944b9_20120828-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/multiarray.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture` would seem to indicate that you're not using a 64-bit python and didn't want to install a 64-bit binary.

Comment: Thank you for the translation. How do I find out what bit (32 or 64) an installation of python uses? (I'm still a complete noob with all this)...

Comment: Generally, the `platform` module, although its documentation suggests checking if `sys.maxsize > 2**32` on OS X to get "64-bit-ness" of the interpreter because universal binaries might have some weird effects.

Comment: Running `file` on your Python interpreter should also work.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you try "import numpy"? Does the traceback still lead to **multiarray.so** with something like:

```
 no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

If so you need to rebuild with the proper archflags, which in your case I'd assume would be x86_64.

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip install numpy
```